# Store Excel File into Postgres

Tags: excel, postgresql

I'm looking for an approach to store Excel file into Postgres. To be clear, I'm not looking for extracting data from Excel and load to Postgres. I want to store the file itself in Postgres, perhaps as XML data type or binary object.

I intend to do ELT on these Excel files, without needing external workflow orchestration/cron.

If somehow I could use Pandas within Postgres using plpython, that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use binary field and write bytes to it.
So you have to open file in binary mode like this:

```
 with open('myfile.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
     binary = f.read()
```

And then write `binary` (which is of type `bytes`) to database using your connector library.

Or also you always can use character field and write base64-encoded file to it, but it will use more space. Although, it's more flexible and compatible way to store binary data as you can store it in any place that supports strings. In that case, use `base64` from Python STL